# How do I determine the lineage of several sets of source code?

Tags: svn, diff, legacy

I have several hundred sets of source code where I know that files were copied from one project to another. Most of the projects were checked into subversion long after the fact (the revision history will be useless). Are there any automated tools which would allow me to figure out which projects were the oldest, and what the family tree of the source code is from there?

Comment: [flay](https://github.com/seattlerb/flay) looks for similarity in code, but I'm not sure it works recursively or with that much source code at once.

Answer (score 0):

If the code contains date information [eg. checkin dates for some previous configuration management tool, etc.] or version information, you should obviously use that as a starting place.

Once you've done that, what you want to do is to compare the source code sets against one another, and form a lineage tree based on minimal distance in terms of edits.  That is, A is likely derived from B if the delta count of (A,B) is less than the delta count of (A,x) and (y,B) for all other x and y in the system, for some definition of delta in terms of lines changed, lines moved, files renamed, files moved, etc.   Also, if the changes from A to B are a subset of the changes from A to C, B is a likely intermediary.

This reduces your problem to detecting "delta count" across pairs of systems and/or comparing delta sets for subsumption.  For this, you probably want a clone detector, which tells you what parts of the code the are the *same*; the complement is what is different.

I don't know if anybody has packaged this up into a neat form for easy use.  The closest you might come is a structural clone detector, see http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stan/PAPERS/CMCA%20Summary.pdf  I don't think this produces fine-grain matching, so the delta count might be a little rough.

If you want finer grain clone detection, and the code is largely in one computer language, you might consider our CloneDR and/or SmartDifferencers, which compare code at the level of abstract syntax trees extracted from language-precise parsers.